# Recurrence Calculator For iCal - RFC 2445

Tags: objective-c, icalendar, rfc2445

I need to interpret a RFC2445 recurrence rule and figure out what dates it occurs on.
I don't really want to get into the nitty-gritty of the standard as it seems quite complex, I was wondering if anyone knows of an Objective-C / C / C++ library that I can use to do this?

I have seen DDay.iCal which seems perfect but it's in C#...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at the ical library on source forge. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/

rahul